# What exactly does "вопще" mean?

Tags: перевод

I've had many people use this with me but I haven't been able to get a good translation on it. Is it the same as вообще?

Comment: Yes, it is just misspelled вообще.

Comment: It's not _just_ misspelled; I'd say it's intentionally misspelled. It's popular nowadays in Russian Internet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Вообще` has several intentional misspellings that reflect its colloquial pronunciations; `вопще` is just one of them, not in any way preferred to `вапще` or even `ваще`. All of them are more likely to reflect the, again, colloquial function of `вообще` as an emotionally laden "completely" or "totally", rather than its other meanings ("in general" or "as a matter of fact"); however, nothing stops the "emotional" `вообще` from being spelt regularly.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you're right. Variations in modern Russian slang:

> **Вообще**: вобще, вопще, вапще
>   **Вообще-то**: вапщета, ващета, [тащемта](http://teenslang.su/content/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: P.S. Feel free to use the correct spelling even if everybody around use "misspelled" versions. However, *тащемта* would have impressed me coming from non-native Russian speaker.

Comment: *тащемта* is a meme rather than a colloquialism. It's already dated and may be a *превед*-grade antiquity in a few more years.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a misspelled word вообще. Usually, used, in similar cases, as English 'actually'. For example: 'Actually, I didn't mean it.', 'It's your turn, actually.', etc.

Answer (score 1):

In general, generally speaking